# paper-datatable not detecting the data-source/data-object defined locally in polymer-element

Tags: polymer-1.0, datatables-1.10, paper-elements

I am trying to use paper-datatable-card in one of my polymer-elements. In data-source i have given a variable which is an array of object.

```
<paper-datatable-card id="datatableCard" header="Checklist" page-size="10" data-source="{{users}}" id-property="id" selected-ids="{{selectedIds}}">
   <paper-datatable id="datatable" selectable multi-selection selected-items="{{selectedItems}}">
        <div no-results>
          Loading or no more items...
        </div>
        <paper-datatable-column header="ID" property="id" type="String" default="1" tooltip="Some title" sortable align="center" sorted></paper-datatable-column>
        <paper-datatable-column header="Task Name" property="name" type="String" defualt="abc" tooltip="PM task" sortable></paper-datatable-column>
   </paper-datatable>      

</paper-datatable-card>
```

Below is the script of my polymer-element :

```
< script >


  Polymer({
    is: 'opt-main',

    properties: {

    },

    ready: function() {
      this.users = [
            {id: 0, name: 'Lily'},
            {id: 1, name: 'Emila'}
        ];
      }

  }); //end-polymer
})(); //end-function  </script >
```

I am not able to see any data in my table. Is there anything wrong in defining the data source ? I am new to polymer so not sure if this is the right way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have got the answer. I had added the data-source in `<paper-datatable-card>` but my columns reside in < paper-datatable > . Adding `data={{users}}` in `<paper-datatable>` will solve this.